# Example of $3$-dimensional $p$-adic group

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras, p-adic-number-theory

**Example of $3$-dimensional $p$-adic group:**

I am searching some examples of $3$- dimensional $p$-adic groups.

However I have touched one such group but I am not sure.

Consider the group $\{\pi \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p) \ | \  \pi \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix} \mod p \}$.

As far as I collected information, there is a $3-$ dimensional Lie algebra associated to this group and hence it is $3-$ dimensional p-adic group.

Can someone share some more details about this group?

Comment: Let $G=\{ A\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z}_p),A-I \in p^2 M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p))$. Then $\log(A) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ (I-A)^k}{k}\in Lie(G)= \{B\in p^2M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p), tr(B)=0\}$ is well-defined as well as $\exp : Lie(G)\to G$ but $\exp$ isn't well-defined on the $\Bbb{Q}_p$-vector space $\bigcup_n p^{-n} Lie(G)$.

Comment: @reuns, Are you trying to say that there is a correspondence between $G$ and $Lie(G)$ trough $\log(A)$ function but not through $\text{exp}$ function ?  Can you leave it as short answer pointing my question? That would help me to understand.

Comment: You should write $SL_2$, not $sl_2$ (which looks like the Lie algebra). But your group is not well-defined. What do you mean by modulo $p$ in $\mathbf{Q}_p$? it works however in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$.

Comment: @YCor, ok I correct. Now how to show that the above group is $3-$ dimensional p-adic group? can you show little work which will help me?

Comment: It's an open subgroup in $SL_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ (or of $SL_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$), so the modulo $p$ assumption plays no role to show it.

Comment: @YCor, so which condition will show that the group is 3-dimensional? Can you  correct the  definition of the above group  in order to be a 3-dimensional p-adic group?

Comment: It is what I did...

Comment: @reuns, $\text{It is}$ means what ? Are you meaning the correspondence $G \to Lie (G)$ ?

Comment: What do you not understand in my first comment ? It is quite obvious $\log$ is surjective $GL_2(Q_p) \cap I+ p^2 M_2(Z_p) \to p^2 M_2(Z_p) $. If I take $p^2 $ instead of $p^1$ it is to make $\exp$ well-defined.

Comment: @reuns, I did not understand how do you conclude dimension of $G$ is $3$. How to show $Lie(G)$ has dimension $3$ in order to conclude $dim (G)=3$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p$ odd prime

- Show $$\log : I+ p^2 M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p) \to p^2 M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p),\qquad \log(A) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ (I-A)^k}{k}$$ is injective (from $\log(I+p^k M) = p^k M+O(p^{2k})$)
- Show $$\exp : p^2 M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p)\to I+ p^2 M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p) $$ is injective (from $\exp(p^k M) =I+ p^k M+O(p^{2k})$)
- $\exp \circ \log = Id$ from our knowledge of complex analysis which extends to formal series thus to p-adic series.

Thus the Lie-algebra of $I+ p^2 M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p)$ is a $4$-dimensional $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module.

Then substract $\log(\det(A)^{-1/2} I)$ to find the image of the restriction to $I+ p^2 M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p) \cap SL_2(\Bbb{Z}_p)$.

The difference with real Lie groups is that $\exp$ doesn't have to extend to the  $\Bbb{Q}_p$-vector space generated by $Lie(G)$.

Comment: Is $M$ is the maximal ideal? If so, then I know from p-adic logarithm properties that $\log(1+p^km)=p^km, \ k >1$. But your $k$ starts at $k=1$. So would not be a problem?

Comment: also explain the 2nd last sentence "Then substract $\log(\det(A)^{-1/2} I)$ to find the image of the restriction to $I+ p^2 M_2(\Bbb{Z}_p) \cap SL_2(\Bbb{Z}_p)$." specially the term $\log(\det(A)^{-1/2} I)$.